# Norm of operator between two $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

In my reading, I've come across notation like $ ||T||_{2 \to \infty} $, where $T$ is an operator defined on every $L^p$ space. What does this mean? Is it simply the norm of $T$ viewed as an operator from $L^2$ to $L^\infty$? Can this norm be expressed in terms of the norms $||T||_2$ and $||T||_{\infty}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you suspect, $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{p,q}$ is the norm $L_p \rightarrow L_q$. In this context $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{2}$ is just $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{2,2}$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I made an edit to clarify what I was asking about the relation between the $|| \cdot ||_{p \to q}$ norm and the $ || \cdot ||_p$ and $ || \cdot ||_q$ norms.

Comment: Hi Jonas. In general there are no tidy relations, but there are some inequalities in the finite dimensional case -- see the Wikipedia article in Matrix norms for example.